# Plone TinyMCE extend

Tags: tinymce, plone

I use Plone 4.1 and Products.TinyMCE 1.3beta-1 (or 1.2.9).
Unfortunately there is no "quote"-Button in the Tiny.

How can I extend the editor?

Regards,
saromba

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a proper  quoting button (and this is not Plone's fault, it's a matter of [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com)) but there are many text styles. Just select a word and apply the desired text style ('pull-quote' maybe). Otherwise, you can always [add a custom button](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/02/16/adding-a-custom-button-to-tinymce/) or a [custom style](http://www.gontztechnologyservices.com/tips-and-instructions/joomla-tips-and-instructions/adding-custom-styles-to-the-styles-drop-down-menu-of-the-tinymce-editor-in-joomla.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also have a look at pypi's tinymceplugins for inspiration:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=tinymceplugins&submit=search